# Promise control flow

Tags: javascript, promise

I am unable to comprehend the flow in the following code

```
function provideError(){
        for(var i=0; i< 100 ; i++){
            console.log("first Loop");
        }
        return new Error("error");
}

function promise1(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    // reject(new Error("alas"))
    reject(provideError())
})
}

promise1().then((result)=>{
    console.log("Resolved error free")
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.error("An error occurred");
})

for(var i = 199 ; i> 100 ; i--){
    console.log(i)
}
```

The correct output for the script file (from the console) is 
a) loop inside provideError function gets printed 100 times 
b) the descending number loop prints completely 
c) finally console.error() line prints the error , since the promise uses reject function

This is what i thought the output should be 
a) as soon as i call promise1 function , the for loop should start in async manner 
b) the last number loop should also set up and run completely (so mingling of the logs) 
c) and then promise's result should be printed

What is wrong with my approach.

Comment: "*the for loop should start in async manner*" - a promise doesn't *make* anything asynchronous. It only helps with dealing things that already *are* asynchronous - and nothing in your code is.

Comment: @Bergi , Can you explain the correct flow to me ?

Comment: @Bergi , there is one issue i have , if adding the code in the promise does not make it asynchronous , then why does the loop at the end prints to the console , before the console.error line ?

Comment: Because `then` and `catch` callbacks are always called asynchronously (but still immediate)